# Выбрать количество записей за каждый час по Timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

Здравствуйте. Помогите написать SQL запрос на выбор количества записей за каждый час. Дата у записи хранится в integer (пример: 1446163200). На выходе должно получится вот так:

```
1446163200 | 10
1446166800 | 7
1446170400 | 15
```

Пробовал написать процедуру:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_graph() RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
    start_date INTEGER := 1446163200;
    end_date INTEGER;
    now INTEGER;
    rows RECORD;
BEGIN

SELECT date_part('epoch', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)::int INTO now;
SELECT orders.date INTO rows FROM orders WHERE orders.date >= start_date;

WHILE start_date <= now LOOP
    end_date := start_date + 3600;
    RETURN NEXT (SELECT start_date AS date, COUNT(date) AS count FROM rows WHERE date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) AS t;
    start_date := end_date;
END LOOP;
END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Но ругается на FROM rows, пишет relation "rows" does not exist.

Пробовал через GROUP BY date_part, но как я понял, она не хочет работать с датой в формате integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    date_part('epoch', date_trunc('hour', to_timestamp(start_date))),
    count(*)
from
    tablename
group by
    date_trunc('hour', to_timestamp(start_date))
```

[тестовый пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2eee5/11)

Comment: В результате выводит одну строку, как если бы я сделал запрос SELECT start_date, COUNT(*) FROM tablename

Comment: и о чём это говорит? добавил в ответ ссылку на sqlfiddle